# Why Are 3pt and 0.0pt plus 3.0pt Different?

Tags: equations, align

I was tuning `abovedisplayskip` and found that `\abovedisplayskip=3pt` and `\abovedisplayskip=0.0pt plus 3.0pt` return different results—the former gives a slightly wider space. For example, the following returns pages 1 and 2 equally spaced only if `0.0pt plus 3.0pt`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
%\abovedisplayskip=3pt
\abovedisplayskip=0.0pt plus 3.0pt
hello. hello. hello.
\begin{equation}
y=x.
\end{equation}
\clearpage

hello. hello. hello.
\begin{align}
y=x.
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Why are `3pt` and `0.0pt plus 3.0pt` different?

Comment: `plus` is the magic word that is used to assign a glue. A `plus 3pt` is an ability to become `3pt`, but default to `0pt`.

Comment: So, for example, ```10pt plus 2pt minus 5pt``` means (1) a 10pt default, (2) 12pt at most, and (3) 5pt at least. Am I correct?

Comment: Correct. Level up: every time you stretch or shrink a glue (deviating from the default), it poses some penalty (based on the math formula to complicated to fit in my memory). All TeX does is to minimize the penalty.