# Setting length using `plus` operator not calculating as expected

Tags: lengths, vspace

Consider the following MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\newlength\myheight
\newlength\mypadding
\setlength{\myheight}{2em}
\setlength{\mypadding}{5em}

\begin{document}
\blindtext\\
\vspace{10em}
\vspace{-\mypadding}\\
This is a sentence that has been vertically shifted.\\
\vspace{\mypadding}\\
\blindtext\\
\end{document}
```

If we, instead of writing `\setlength{\mypadding}{5em}`, have `\setlength{\mypadding}{3em plus \myheight}`, we *should* get the same result (as 3 + 2 = 5).  However, as you see if you run this code and compare the outputs, these do not produce the same result.  Why is this?

Comment: no, plus is not calculating. It is for adding a stretch component. Use \addtolength to add something, or use package calc.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I see, thank you for letting me know.  You can add this as an answer so that I can mark this as solved, or I can write up the answer mentioning your help.

Comment: also all those `\\ ` at end of paragraph are destroying the spacing in your document `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 11--17` tex is warning you 10000 is it's _maximum_ level of how bad the output is.

Comment: the same question was asked yesterday as it happens  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/564242/why-are-3pt-and-0-0pt-plus-3-0pt-different